# Questions about a certain sequence of naturals generated by primorials

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series

I'm working on the following sequence of naturals (which is NOT listed in OEIS)
$$3,5,11,17,23,29,59,89,119,149,179,209,419,629,839,1049,1259,1469,1679,...$$
whose elements are generated this way
$$3=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot(1)$$
$$5=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot(p_2-1)$$
$$11=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot((p_2-1)+p_2\cdot(1))$$
$$17=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot((p_2-1)+p_2\cdot(2))$$
$$23=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot((p_2-1)+p_2\cdot(3))$$
$$29=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot((p_2-1)+p_2\cdot(p_3-1))$$
$$59=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot((p_2-1)+p_2\cdot((p_3-1)+p_3\cdot(1)))$$
$$...$$
$$209=(p_1-1)+p_1\cdot((p_2-1)+p_2\cdot((p_3-1)+p_3\cdot(p_4-1)))$$
$$...$$
where $p_i$ stands for the $i$-th prime. It's quite evident that the sequence is generated by adding the primorials $p_i\#$.

By construction, each element $\,m\,$ of the sequence has the following property:
$$m\equiv -1\mod p_i\;$$
for each $\,i\lt k\,$ where $\,k\,$ is the first index such that $\,p_k\# \gt m$.

If we truncate the sequence at the last element generated by using only the first $n$ primes (id est, for example, $209\,$ for $\,n=3$), the whole number of elements is given by
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(p_{i+1}-1)=(\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}p_i)-n\sim \frac12n^2\log n$$

But what about the number of primes in the sequence (3,5,11,17,23,29,59,89,149,179,419,...)?

Some numeric experiments let me suppose that the number of primes in the truncated sequence above defined could be $\sim 2\,n\log n$.

Is it the correct asymptotical behavior? Could anybody give me the sketch of a proof?

Many thanks.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you construct your sequence ("succession"). Could you explain in words how it's constructed, instead of just listing a bunch of terms?

Comment: You start from $3=1+2#$, then add $2#=2$ till you remain under $3#=6$ (that is $5$). Now you continue adding $3#$ unti you remain under $5#=30$. This way you obtain the elements $11,17,23,29$. At this point you have to continue adding $5#$, obtaining  $59$ and so on ...

Comment: I checked: the sequence is not present in the OEIS database.